# Where are List informations stored in ApachePoi's XWPFDocument?

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I want to merge two or more docx files (append them after each other) or move one part of the document(XWPFParagraph) to other place.

The problem is that listings always breaks after such an operation. Say we have a listing in a document which has sequence numbers then we have other listing in another document which has bullets or letters. Than after the copy all of the bullets becomes numbers (or worse numbers which starts from where the previous listing has been ended).

I have tried several solutions :
-traversing BodyElements and copying Paragraphs and Tables by hand like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130419/how-to-copy-some-content-in-one-docx-to-another-docx-using-poi-without-losin). 
-attaching a newBody into an existing one like here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531237/how-can-i-merge-more-than-two-word-documents-with-apache-poi)

Aside from page scoped styles they work well. But the listings never. Is that means the listing symbols are stored as page scoped information (otherwise it would be copyied successfully with the XWPFParagraph)? If yes than why and where?

I have dig myself into the javadoc: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html 
But couldn't find anything about the listings.

Comment: I don't know Apache, but I do know the underlying Word Open XML, so this information *might* help you: Numbered lists are controlls by `ListTemplate` definitions. A ListTemplate is a numbering definition stored centrally in the document. A reference to it is part of the paragraph-level formatting. But it's possible that the definition of a given ListTemplate reference ID is *different* in another document, so the paragraph being imported would pick up the ListTemplate definition of the target document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Word` numberings (numbered lists but bullet lists also) in `Office Open XML` file format are stored in `/word/numbering.xml` of the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive. There are `abstractNum` elements describing the list format and `num` elements referencing the `abstractNum`. The `numId` of the `num`elements are referenced in paragraphs of `/word/document.xml` to set which numbering formats shall be used in that paragraph. Paragraphs referencing the same `numId` are in the same list.
Paragraphs referencing different `numId` are in different lists.

In `apache poi` there are [XWPFNumbering](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFNumbering.html) representing the document part `/word/numbering.xml` and [XWPFAbstractNum](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFAbstractNum.html) representing the `abstractNum`.

Until now there is no way creating `XWPFAbstractNum` from scratch without using the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes.

Also, as far as I know, there is no simple way to merge `/word/numbering.xml` document parts of different `Word` documents because of the need handling the different `Id`s in `/word/numbering.xml` as well as their occurrences in `/word/document.xml`. This is very complex and I do not know any free library which can do this properly.

In general, as far as I know, there is no simple way to merge different `Word` documents together because of the complex storage in `Word` file formats. All provided possibilities using free code are only halfway useful (traversing and copying), if not wrong and useless (simply attaching multiple document bodys one after the other) at all.